# Meaning of referer param fb_source=games_ego

Tags: facebook, http-referer

I see many people coming to my facebook game with HTTP referer that includes
fb_source=games_ego

Previously all options were at
http://fbdevwiki.com/index.php?title=Ref&cb=7347
but "games_ego" is something new.

What could it mean?

Comment: Unofficial docs were updated too - http://fbdevwiki.com/index.php?title=Ref&cb=3313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's new section "Discover New Games" in the right block which is shown only in games.

[image: Discover new Games]

Official Facebook documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/measurement#referraltracking

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they just changed it, but I only see "fb_source=ego".  I updated the wiki.

Also, on the wiki there's a link to where Facebook has documented the possible values.